# Write this piece wise function in terms of the unit step function unit step

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$$f(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}  1,  & 0\leqslant t <1\\
       -2, & 1\leqslant t\leqslant2 \\
       0,  & t>2 \end{array}\right.$$

I got a long drawn out answer that can't possibly be right.

Answer (score 1):

The only 'difficulty' is dealing with the $t=2$ point.

Assuming that $u=1_{[0,\infty)}, v=1_{(0,\infty)}$, we have

$f(t) = (u(t) - u(t-1)) -2 (u(t-1)-v(t-2)) $.

Now note that $v(t) = 1-u(-t)$, so

$f(t) = (u(t) - u(t-1)) -2 (u(t-1)+u(2-t)-1) $.